# How to get texture finish on packaging

Tags: print-design, texture, packaging

Dear professional designers,

I have questions regarding to creating packaging texture.

I am intersected in creating a packaging design with a little paper texture.

See 2 example below.

I was wondering...

-How do I achieve that small subtle texture on the paper?

-Do I have to create my own texture and tell it to the printer company? 
-Do printer company just emboss the the texture?
-Or the texture comes with the paper?

Thank you so much for your help!

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/avVsL.jpg)

[image]

[image]

What about this type of texture? This is letterpress. Is that correct? 
[image]

Comment: Welcome! You realize in your sample images the texture is the substrate (Item actually being printed on) don't you? It's not part of the artwork. The artwork is the same as any artwork, not textured. Are you asking how to mimic texture?

Comment: A printer company prints or engrave the paper (the Rapha text... Cool name!). A manufacturer of paper is the one that should make that textured paper, not the printer.

Comment: Thank you so much. Since the texture (I thought) is the substrate. It must be expensive I guess.

Comment: That last one you added is indeed a printing processes, not the substrate.

Answer (score 3):

The text in one and two are **debossed** (or **stamped**), the gold text is **embossed**. All three also use *foil*. Foil is not required and the effect can be quite elegant without it.

You will need to have a die made. Embossing usually involves stamping from the back of the paper and is quite visible from behind. To hide the back, you can laminate a second sheet (or fold and trim an oversized sheet) after the emboss.

The items in one and two, the texture is a property of the paper (or possibly fabric etc.) and the text is stamped into it, smoothing it. In the third image, it is smooth paper and the texture of the text is a property given to it by the die.

An emboss die is right-reading, and a deboss/stamp is flopped (aka flipped, left-reading, wrong-reading). The cost depends on the print run and the size. I don't recall the ones I have had made costing more than maybe an extra $1 per unit on a less than 10,000 run. It has been a while though.